# Can sum() be used like a hash

Tags: python, list, hash, sum, compare

I want to check whether the sum of two list is same or not.

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst2 = [0, 3, 3, 4]
if sum(lst1) == sum(lst2):
    return true
```

Here the sum returns true. If I hash the list I get different values but hashing is computationally expensive. **I only want to check whether the elements in the two lists are same (only with the exception of 1 element)**. I am using Binary search technique of dividing the list and then checking the hash. if hashes are different I am checking if its more than once.
But as I said hashing is computationally expensive. **Also the order does matter here**. Thank you

Comment: You don't need the sum then. Enough to check the lists have the same items. You didn't say if the order is important tho.

Comment: You could use `hash(tuple(lst))` to generate a distinctive number for a list. But it wouldn't be unique. It's impossible to convert a list to a unique number unless there is additional information about (say) the range of the numbers in your lists.

Comment: Your sum *is* equal. It *should* return True.

Comment: Re-opened after the OP's edit.  The question is now entirely unrelated to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Can sum be used like a hash?

Yes, the *sum()* function can be used as a hash for a list or tuple of integers.

### Is hashing is computationally expensive?

Interestingly, ***hash()* performs better than *sum()* for a tuple of integers**:

```
$ python2.7 -m timeit -s "data = (1, 2, 3, 4)" "sum(data)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.113 usec per loop

$ python2.7 -m timeit -s "data = (1, 2, 3, 4)" "hash(data)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0569 usec per loop
```

### How to compare unordered lists

The stated problem is "how to compare elements in the two lists are same (only with the exception of 1 element)"

A built-in tool for doing this is [*collections.Counter()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  Internally, it uses fast hashing to accumulate counts.  In Python 3, it is accelerated by code written in C.   It uses a single O(n) pass rather than an O(log n) binary search.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list2 = [0, 3, 3, 4]

>>> c1 = Counter(list1)
>>> c2 = Counter(list2)
>>> c1 == c2
False
>>> c1 - c2
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1})
>>> c2 - c1
Counter({0: 1, 3: 1})
```

The difference in the various approaches will become more pronounced as the list size grows larger.

Answer (score 5):

First, `is` is not the logically correct syntax for your application; use `==` instead. Refer this post to know more about the difference: [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

```
def checksum(lst1, lst2):
    return sum(lst1) == sum(lst2):

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [0, 3, 3, 4]
checksum(list1,list2)
```

This *is* the correct code to compare a *checksum* (and is obviously true in this example).

If you are looking for something different, like finding whether the items of the list are the same element-wise, then the straight-forward answer would be

```
return lst1 == lst2
```

Comment: *but sum should differentiate between the different numbers in the list*

Comment: This is a good tip but it's really not what the OP was asking.

Comment: Should have been in a comment indeed - or as a side note in a full answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion bruno and @khelwood. I just added a bit more detail for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

`is` checks for object identity, not equality ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)).

`sum` does not differentiate between the elements that are summed over only the end result. If you need to differentiate between the elements of the containers you can use a `set`

```
set(lst1) == set(lst2) # ignores counts of elements
```

or if you're sensitive to the counts of the elements use `collections.Counter`

```
collections.Counter(lst2) == collections.Counter(lst1) # False
collections.Counter(lst1) == collections.Counter(lst1) # True
```

this requires you to iterate over the list.

---

Depending on what exactly you're after you could also you

```
hash(tuple(lst1)) == hash(tuple(lst2))
```

This checks both the elements contained and their order (maybe you don't care about order) and is pretty efficient. You have to do the cast to a `tuple` as `list` is not immutable and therefore can not be hashed.

`hash(tuple)` seems to be much faster, but it's not clear to me what exactly your end goal is

```
%timeit hash(tuple(lst1)) == hash(tuple(lst2))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 408 ns per loop

%timeit collections.Counter(lst2) == collections.Counter(lst1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.58 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1), but don't you think it's a bit of an overkill for the OP?

Comment: I try to write my answers for anyone stumbling onto the question later in addition to the OP.  SO is a form of documentation nowadays